# Can nested arrays/join be done with Php::PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

Im affraid I ask too much, but I dont want to code it if its possible.
There is an "users (ID, USERNAME)" and a "pictures (ID, USER_ID, NAME)" table. If you want to get the images of users, you would simply use:

SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN pictures ON pictures.USER_ID = users.ID;

but that returns a simple associative array. I would want to see something like this:

```
 ID => 1
 USERNAME => "user1";
 pictures => array();

 ID => 1
 USERNAME => "user2";
 pictures => array();

 ID => 1
 USERNAME => "user3";
 pictures => array(
    ID => 1
    USER_ID => 3
    NAME = "picture of user3"
 )
```

so I want to see a nested multidimensinal associated array, I dont know if I ask too much from PDO. I guess somewhere I should set foreign keys for PDO. Any ideas? Can it be done? Im new to PDO

Comment: BTW, all the automation PDO is able to is listed on the fetchAll() man page

Comment: This has little to do with `PDO` in itself, Foreign keys don't make a DB work differently. Fetching a multi-dimensional result-set isn't how MySQL rolls. Just prepare a `SELECT * FROM pictures` statement, loop over the users, and fetch the related data (of course, proper indexing is always a good idea)

Comment: so SELECT * FROM users, and another SELECT * FROM pictures inside a loop? I would be immediatly fired :)))))

Comment: @JohnSmith: No, I said: prepare a statement, not `SELECT *` in a loop: `$stmt2->execute(array(':userId' => $user->id)); $user->pictures = $stmt2->fetchAll(); $stmt2->closeCursor();` PS: `SELECT * FROM users` would be reason enough to fire someone 99% of the time

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem his initial query considered better from architectural point of view. Yet simple condition inside the loop will help to filter out duplicate names and group pictures together.

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is no, it can't be done. It has nothing to do with PDO, though. It has everything to do with MySQL: MySQL isn't PHP. Its job is to store, and fetch data. If you `JOIN` 2 or more tables, and fetch the result, then the DB will be happy to do so.
The data will then be fetched *"as is"*, that is to say: in pretty much the same way the data was stored. If you want a 2D array, that would imply the data is stored in a table, that contains fields that are in itself tables. MySQL doesn't do that: it has no nested tables (MS SQL Server *can* do this, by storing XML in fields, for example).

However, PHP *can* process the data returned by the query, using a simple loop:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query(
    'SELECT u.*, p.id as picture_id, p.name as picture_name
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN pictures p
      ON u.id = p.user_id
');
$endResult = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if (!isset($endResult[$row['id']]))
        $endResult[$row['id']] = array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'username' => $row['username'],
            'pictures' => array();
        );
    $endResult[$row['id']]['pictures'][] = array(
        'id' => $row['picture_id'],
        'name' => $row['picture_name']
    );
}
```

It really is *that* simple. And as you well may know: K.I.S.S is most important. What follows now is purely academic. The code listed below ***should not be used***, but I got a bit carried away, and it seemed a shame to not *"preserve"* the queries my moment of madness spawned... So I posted it here

---

## This code is not meant to be used. Ever!

Doing so may result in serious and permanent damage to yourself, those around you and humanity in general. If you are the sort of person who, at any point while reading the rest of this answer might think *"Hey, I might use this"*, read no further. And get help.

Of course, there are other options. You could, for example, reduce the number of rows you fetch by grouping the resultset by the users' id. If you do so, you'll have to `GROUP_CONCAT` the values found in the `pictures` table. I wouldn't recommend doing this, because it displaces logic: logic belongs in the application, not on a DB server, or in queries, just know that it is possible:

```
SELECT u.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) AS picture_ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) AS picture_names
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN pictures p?
  ON u.id = p.user_id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

By default, MySQL will concatenate the values found in the `pictures` table using comma's as a separator. In which case, it's a simple matter of `explode`-ing the results into an array:

```
$results = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $pictures = array();
    $ids = explode(',', $row['picture_ids']);
    $names = explode(',', $row['picture_names']);
    foreach ($ids as $k => $id)
    {
        $pictures[] = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $names[$k]
        );
    }
    $results[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'username' => $row['username'],
        'pictures' => $pictures
    );
}
```

Of course, the code above will fail completely the moment a picture's name contains a comma, so it might be best to change the delimiter used by `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(p.name, '@#@#@')
```

Or, to `REPLACE` comma's with semicolons:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(p.name, ',', ';'))
```

But since we're digging this far down: In for a penny, in for a pound, you might as well write a query that selects the `pictures` data as a json encoded string. What do we need to do for that? Simple:

- `CONCAT` the data into a string format like `[{"id":%d, "name":"%s"]}`, where %d will be an int, and %s is the picture's name.
- We also have to make sure that the picture's name will not contain `"`, because that'll result in malformed JSON. Adding an escaping `\` is dangerous, because such a backslash might already be present.
- Fetch the data, and `json_decode` the `pictures` data.

The resulting query is ridiculously complex for such a simple task, but here it is:

```
SELECT u.*,
  CONCAT(
    '[',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      CONCAT(
        '{"id":',
        p.id,
        ',"name":"',
        REPLACE(
          p.name,
          '"',
          '&quot;'
        ),
        '"}'
      )
    ),
    ']'
) AS pictures
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN pictures p
  ON u.id = p.user_id
GROUP_BY u.id;
```

In your PHP script, write:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query();//<-- the query from above
$result = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $row['pictures'] = json_decode($row['pictures'], true);
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

But let's be honest, it's just not worth the trouble. Just execute your query as is, and write that simple loop I used in the beginning of my answer. Because this last snippet [Though fully functional](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35942/19), is just idiotic. If this really is the kind of data you want your DB to return, switch to a [NoSQL alternative](http://nosql-database.org/) like mongoDB, instead of re-working this query to end up with something only a lunatic would look at and think of it as a possibility:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    '{"id":',
    u.id,
    ',"username":"',
    REPLACE(
      u.username,'"','&quot;'
    ),'","pictures":',
      CONCAT(
    '[',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      CONCAT(
        '{"id":',
        p.id,
        ',"name":"',
        REPLACE(
          p.name,
          '"',
          '&quot;'
        ),
        '"}'
      )
    ),
    ']'
  ),
  '}'
) AS full_json
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN pictures p
  ON u.id = p.user_id
GROUP_BY u.id;
//in PHP:
$result = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $result = json_decode($row['full_json'], true);
```

But in case you are wondering: [it does work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35942/21).

Comment: @YourCommonSense: I don't know how many times I explicitly say the exact same thing in my answer, but I do agree. I call this JSON-creating business _"idiotic"_ and _"mad"_ more than once...

Comment: could you both explain what you mean? Would you say that a JSON object representing something like a xml or html document is mad too? If yes, why? Better ways to deal with hierarchical structures in php? And: How would you represent those in a DB? Your explanation is welcome. Just giving an opinion without explanation doesnt help

Comment: @Sasha: I've never said (or tried to say) that storing something in JSON format is mad. Not at all, I love JSON. Storing data as JSON in MySQL, though, that's a different story, especially if you need to query on a particular value, somewhere in the JSON (or XML) object. The moment you start doing that, either look into NoSQL alternatives, or don't store the data as JSON/XML or any other serialization format. To MySQL, JSON is just text, it's not indexed or parsed, using queries to generate JSON or queries that attempt to parse JSON is mad, using JSON or XML isn't: it's common sense :)

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem: ok, think I got it, thx. So, when I don't want to use a NoSQL but still want to store document-oriented data, the method of choice would be to break this data down to relational data and further on, after querying this data, a) assemble it to JSON using PHP or b) even better work in 'relational mode' and represent the nested JSON structure in a later step on object level (e.g. by using container arrays to inject objects of the underlying level into them)? Or is it just case dependent? Just let me know if I got this common sense thing (to suck this joke dry ;-)

Comment: @sasha: That sounds about right... but as you say: it's not a black/white sort of deal: depending on your needs, it's perfectly OK to store a piece of data as a JSON string in a mysql table, provided there's enough other data (ID's etc) to query that data, and to use it in a relational structure.

Comment: @Your Common Sense unless you are forced to use mysql old as heck so you cant use `JSON_OBJECT`.